# How to find html attributes with part of attribute name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to find all the attributes in my html page that has "data" in it. When I have those, I need to remove them (or just remove all the values in it). Anyone got a suggestion?

Example: My html is the following:

```
<section id="slide-2">
                <div class="bcg" data-center="background-color: #f0f0f0">
                    <div class="hsContainer">
                        <div class="hsContent">

                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="span12">
                                        <header data-center="opacity: 1" data-100-top="opacity: 1" data-1-top="opacity: 0">
                                            <img src="img/headers/pencil.png" alt="pencil">
                                            <h1>Het concept</h1>
                                        </header>

                                        <p data-center="opacity: 1" data-100-top="opacity: 1" data-1-top="opacity: 0">“Het creëren van een omgeving die de mens afsluit van alle schadelijke straling en radiatie op een unieke stralingsvrije locatie in België.“
                                        <br/> Gesteund door Toerisme Vlaanderen.
                                        </p>

                                        <div id="logobox" data-center="opacity: 1" data-100-top="opacity: 1" data-1-top="opacity: 0">
                                            <img src="img/concept/logo.png" alt="logo">
                                            <img src="img/concept/toerismevlaanderen.png" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

I need to get all the attributes where the name contains "data" and clear the value of the attribute.

Comment: So the attribute name has data in it or the attribute value?

Comment: provide a example please

Comment: @Musa The attribute name has "data" in it.

Comment: @keshu_vats provided one

Comment: @keshu_vats updated the question again. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: will you use jquery or simple javascript ?

Comment: @keshu_vats Jquery preferably

Comment: `$('*').each(funtion(){ if($(this).hasAttribute('data-center')){alert($(this).attr('data-center'));$(this).removeAttr('data-center');}});` may this helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('*').each(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    $.each(this.attributes, function(key){
        if (key.indexOf('data') > -1){
            elem.attr(key, '');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it with the help of dataset api of html5 prefer jsfiddle

```
    var element  = document.getElementsById('myDiv');
    var datasets = element.dataset;

    $.each(datasets,function(key,val){element.dataset.key = '';});

http://jsfiddle.net/adeshpandey/N6W8s/3/
```

Note: Please load jquery before using this code. :P

Comment: if yo have more than one elements with data.... attributes then you have to read whole document and then loop through each element.

Answer (score -1):

Use `$(":contains('data')")`

OR

You can also use this link: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-custom-data-attributes

Hope this helps.! All the best.! :)